# Lambda to both Expression Tree and Delegate Instance

Tags: c#, expression

A lambda in C#, provided it is a single expression without braces declaring a body, can be both compiled down into an expression tree (via the `Expression<TDel>` type) or a delegate instance (`Func<...>`, `Action<...>`, and friends) based on the inferred usage.

My question is: is there a way of tricking the language/compiler into making both representations from the same lambda declaration, tree and delegate, available without repeating yourself?

In other words, can this be done without explicitly asking for the expression tree and then running a `.Compile()` on it?

If not, are there reasons to believe deferring the compilation to this run-time method doesn't carry that much of an impact in the .NET implementation? In my specific use case these lambdas have no capture group, meaning if no compile-time solution exists I could still warm them up and cache them manually, but... eh, that's another can of worms.

Comment: I don't know of any way of doing this, no. I'd just use the `Compile()` option.

Comment: Could this be done with a Roslyn extension?

Comment: @Romoku You could write an extension to the language that would do this, or an IDE feature that would handle the duplication for you, in either case it wouldn't be the C# language itself supporting this.

Comment: I suppose particular method calls `obj.Method<T,TRet>(x => x.Id)` can be rewritten as `x.Method(x => x.Id, x => x.Id)` where the argument types cover both cases (`Expression<Func<T,TRet>>` and `Func<T,TRet>`).

Alas, if only there was a way to bind a variable to a lambda literal instead of them decaying right away.